# PL/SQL no data found

Tags: oracle, plsql

I cant seem to figure out why it says no data found. The table is populated so why isn't it finding the data when I am pulling it? I tried a few different ways but keep coming up with the same error.

this is the newemp table:

```
SQL> select *
  2  from newemp;

     EMPNO ENAME      JOB              MGR HIREDATE         SAL       COMM
---------- ---------- --------- ---------- --------- ---------- ----------
    DEPTNO
----------
      7369 SMITH      CLERK           7902 17-DEC-80        800
        20

      7499 ALLEN      SALESMAN        7698 20-FEB-81       1600        300
        30

      7521 WARD       SALESMAN        7698 22-FEB-81       1250        500
        30

      7566 JONES      MANAGER         7839 02-APR-81       2975
        20

      7654 MARTIN     SALESMAN        7698 28-SEP-81       1250       1400
        30

      7698 BLAKE      MANAGER         7839 01-MAY-81       2850
        30

      7782 CLARK      MANAGER         7839 09-JUN-81       2450
        10

      7788 SCOTT      ANALYST         7566 19-APR-87       3000
        20

      7839 KING       PRESIDENT            17-NOV-81       5000
        10

      7844 TURNER     SALESMAN        7698 08-SEP-81       1500          0
        30

      7876 ADAMS      CLERK           7788 23-MAY-87       1100
        20

      7900 JAMES      CLERK           7698 03-DEC-81        950
        30

     7902 FORD       ANALYST         7566 03-DEC-81       3000
        20

      7934 MILLER     CLERK           7782 23-JAN-82       1300
        10
```

And this is my PL/SQL code that keeps coming up with this error:

```
SET VERIFY OFF
DECLARE
   v_ename    newemp.ename%TYPE; 
   v_sal      newemp.sal%TYPE;
   v_newgoal  newemp.deptno%TYPE;
   v_deptno   newemp.deptno%TYPE;
BEGIN
   SELECT ename, sal, deptno INTO v_ename, v_sal, v_deptno
   FROM newemp
   WHERE ename = v_ename;
   IF v_deptno = 10 then 
           v_newgoal := v_sal * 1.05;
         else  
          if v_deptno = 20 then 
          v_newgoal := v_sal * 1.075;
        else 
         v_newgoal := v_sal * 1.1;
 END IF;
END IF;
   UPDATE newemp
   SET sal = v_newgoal
   WHERE ename = v_ename;
COMMIT;
END;
/
SET VERIFY ON
```

The error is:

```
SQL> @ loop1
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01403: no data found
ORA-06512: at line 7
```

**When I add exceptions it says the PL/SQL procedure is complete but does not update the table**

New code with update that still doesnt update:

```
SET VERIFY OFF
DECLARE
   v_ename    newemp.ename%TYPE; 
   v_sal      newemp.sal%TYPE;
   v_newgoal  newemp.deptno%TYPE;
   v_deptno   newemp.deptno%TYPE;
BEGIN
   v_ename := 'NULL';

   begin
     SELECT ename, sal, deptno INTO v_ename, v_sal, v_deptno
     FROM newemp
     WHERE ename = v_ename;
   exception when no_data_found then 
          return;
   end;

   IF v_deptno = 10 then 
           v_newgoal := v_sal * 1.05;
         else  
          if v_deptno = 20 then 
          v_newgoal := v_sal * 1.075;
        else 
         v_newgoal := v_sal * 1.1;
 END IF;
END IF;
   UPDATE newemp
   SET sal = v_newgoal
   WHERE ename = v_ename;
COMMIT;
END;
/
SET VERIFY ON
```

Comment: You declared `v_ename` in DECLARE section, but you didn't assign any value to it, so it was NULL. Because of this the first `SELECT .. WHERE ename = v_ename` statement didn't find any record and threw the error.

Comment: what would I assign to it, it has to be in a constant loop, not selecting one person to update.

Comment: `v_ename := 'my_value';`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your code you didn't assign any values to variable `v_ename`
what you need is add some logic to assign it.

additionally you need check that the values exists in your table or instead of the check catch exception.

your example with this modifications below:

```
SET VERIFY OFF
DECLARE
   v_ename    newemp.ename%TYPE; 
   v_sal      newemp.sal%TYPE;
   v_newgoal  newemp.sal%TYPE;
   v_deptno   newemp.deptno%TYPE;
BEGIN
   --assign some value
   v_ename := null; --if null - it updates all records in table

   for rc in (SELECT ename, sal, deptno
     FROM newemp
     WHERE ename = nvl(v_ename, ename)) loop

   IF rc.deptno = 10 then 
           v_newgoal := rc.sal * 1.05;
         else  
          if rc.deptno = 20 then 
             v_newgoal := rc.sal * 1.075;
           else 
             v_newgoal := rc.sal * 1.1;
           END IF;
   END IF;

   UPDATE newemp
     SET sal = v_newgoal
   WHERE ename = rc.ename;

   end loop;

COMMIT;
END;
/
SET VERIFY ON
```

same logic but more simple code

```
declare
  v_ename    newemp.ename%TYPE;
begin
  v_ename := 'employee_name'; --use null if you need update all employees
UPDATE newemp
   SET sal = 
     case 
       when v_deptno = 10 then sal * 1.05
       when v_deptno = 20 then sal * 1.075
       else sal * 1.1     
     end          
   WHERE ename = nvl(v_ename,ename);
end;
```

Comment: when i used your code it did not update the table, it kept the same values in sal

Comment: it has to be and if else loop..i would much rather use a case

Comment: i will try and use it but i have to use and if else, I update my first post to show you what i did

Comment: im getting errors with the exception when using nvl

Comment: I will try, still such a noob at this

Comment: SQL> @ loop1
DECLARE
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-06502: PL/SQL: numeric or value error: number precision too large
ORA-06512: at line 18

Comment: bcz there's a mistake in types... `v_newgoal  newemp.deptno%TYPE;` should be `v_newgoal  newemp.sal%TYPE;`

Comment: that worked but dept 30 doesnt show anything the sal field is blank

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96315/discussion-on-answer-by-are-pl-sql-no-data-found).

Answer (score 0):

So, why use PL/SQL at all and just use a single SQL query?

```
UPDATE newemp
SET    sal   = CASE DEPTNO
               WHEN 10 THEN sal * 1.05
               WHEN 20 THEN sal * 1.075
                       ELSE sal * 1.1
               END;
```

If this is for some sort of assessment and you must use PL/SQL then:

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7bee1/1)

**Oracle 11g R2 Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE NEWEMP (EMPNO, ENAME, JOB, MGR, HIREDATE, SAL, COMM, DEPTNO ) AS
          SELECT 7369, 'SMITH', 'CLERK', 7902, DATE '1980-12-17', 800, NULL, 20 FROM DUAL
UNION ALL SELECT 7499, 'ALLEN', 'SALESMAN', 7698, DATE '1981-02-20', 1600, 300, 30 FROM DUAL
/

DECLARE
  CURSOR c_employees
  IS  SELECT   EMPNO, DEPTNO, SAL
      FROM     newemp
      FOR UPDATE OF SAL;
BEGIN
   FOR v_row IN c_employees
   LOOP
    IF    v_row.DEPTNO = 10 THEN v_row.SAL := v_row.SAL * 1.05;
    ELSIF v_row.DEPTNO = 20 THEN v_row.SAL := v_row.SAL * 1.075;
                            ELSE v_row.SAL := v_row.SAL * 1.1;
    END IF;

    UPDATE NEWEMP
    SET    SAL   = v_row.SAL
    WHERE  EMPNO = v_row.EMPNO;
   END LOOP;
END;
/
```

**Query 1**:

```
SELECT *
FROM   NEWEMP
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/7bee1/1/0)**:

```
| EMPNO | ENAME |      JOB |  MGR |                   HIREDATE |  SAL |   COMM | DEPTNO |
|-------|-------|----------|------|----------------------------|------|--------|--------|
|  7369 | SMITH |    CLERK | 7902 | December, 17 1980 00:00:00 |  860 | (null) |     20 |
|  7499 | ALLEN | SALESMAN | 7698 | February, 20 1981 00:00:00 | 1760 |    300 |     30 |
```

Comment: it has to be a loop and update the whole table, i cannot choose a name has to just accept the pl/sql and update the whole table

Comment: @JeffMercier updated to use PL/SQL and update the entire table.